# Throw an exception in Apex if attachment is null

Tags: apex, visualforce, exception, dmlexception

I have a Visualforce form that takes attachments of which I need to make required in order for the user to proceed to the next screen. Since the record doesn't get inserted until the end of the multi-step form, I can't validate whether the user has uploaded an attachment or not.

I am wondering if we can throw an exception if an attachment is null. Each `pageReference` method I have redirects the user to the next step (visualforce page) once they're done inputting fields on the current page. So I need to throw the exception in one of these methods like such:

```
public PageReference step4(){
        
    PageReference pageRef3;
    PageRef3 = Page.AWF_Employment;
    PageRef3.setRedirect(false);
    if(ID == null){
        ApexPages.addMessage(
            new ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
                'You must upload your ID'
            )
        );
        return null;
    }
    return Page.AWF_Employment;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `ApexPages.addMessage`?

Comment: Thanks will look into it. Does it stop the execution of the code though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an exception, and not catching it, will result in a page crash. The user will lose everything they were working on up to that point. You should instead display an error and return a null page reference.

```
if(ID == Null){
  ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
      'You need to have an attachment first.'
    )
  );
  return null;
} 
return Page.nextStep;
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that it still redirects to the next page even though there was no attachment uploaded since the `return` statement is outside of the if statement - is there a way to stop the user from being redirected to the next page unless they upload the attachment?

Comment: @SpicyPat The return statement stops function execution. If you get as far as adding the message, no redirect should happen, either. You may need to change your variable name or something else might be going on.

Comment: Edited my code, this is still returning the next VF page even though the `ID` attachment is null